# Using ColdFusion REST API, how do I return a response in onError handler?

Tags: api, rest, coldfusion

I'm trying to set up a REST Web Services with ColdFusion 10, and if I have an onError handler in  Application.cfc to handle incorrect parameter error.

My Download API Service:

```
<cfcomponent rest="true" restpath="downloadStuff">
    <cffunction name="downloadStuff" access="remote" returntype="String" httpmethod="GET">
        <!--- parameters --->
        <cfargument name="id" required="true" type="string" restargsource="query"/>
        <cfargument name="account" required="true" type="string" restargsource="query"/>
        <!--- download stuff logic ---> 
        ...
        <cfreturn response> 
    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

It is expecting 2 parameters and user get a 500 error if parameters are not there. I don't want user to see the 500 error, I want user to see a normal response message asking user to add the missing parameter.

This is my onError handler in application.cfc

```
<cffunction name="onError" returntype="String" output="true">
    <cfargument name="exception" required="true">
    <cfargument name="eventname" type="string" required="true">
    <!--- error logging here --->
    <cfset response = "Please add missing parameters">

    <cfreturn response>
```

When user enter incorrect parameters to API, I am getting 500 error with "cannot convert the value "Please add missing parameters" to a boolean".

How can I pass back a response message in onError? Is there a better way to handle incorrect parameters error and return a message to user?

Comment: You should be able to use the `restSetResponse` function for this. `<cfset restSetResponse(returnStruct)>`.

Comment: yes I added restSetResponse instead returning a response and it worked

Comment: @help could you pls consider posting your answer *as an actual answer*, and mark it accepted?